# Jenkins MultiJob plugin doesn't run in desired order

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I wanted to test the MultiJob plugin locally before using it on a larger (more important) server. I wanted it to run test jobs sequentially and to test this I got each job to print a line to a text file. This seemed to work fine until I noticed that it didn't complete the jobs in the desired order.

I was wondering why this happened and if there was a better way to do this as if the first job wasn't built before the second job the system would fail.
At the moment it finishes the 2nd job first despite configuring the job correctly as far as I am aware.

I also tried to use the parameterised trigger plugin but this doesn't automatically deploy one job after the other, just displays the projects as either an upstream project or a downstream project, or both.

[image: Image to show MultiJob plugin contents]

[image: Text file displaying order of jobs]

Comment: I removed all the parameterized triggers and ran it again, slightly better result this time but test02-02 still ran before test02-01.

Comment: I have same problem...you have resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed with the release of the Multijob plugin version 1.24 (Mar 15, 2017). It addresses issue [JENKINS-37351](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37351) in which jobs run in a different order than defined.

**Update the Multijob plugin to version 1.24!**

I stumbled across this issue too and was able to verify that the jobs defined in a phase are executed sequentially in the given order.